# Consulta que retorna a diferença em horas entre duas datas considerando dias úteis - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query, data

Estou com uma demanda onde preciso gerar uma consulta que retorne a quantidade de registros existentes numa tabela, dado a diferença, em horas, entre duas datas.

A diferença entre as datas consigo pegar da seguinte maneira:

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, date1, date2)`

Ocorre que preciso considerar os dias úteis (seg a sex), das 08:00h às 18:00h e sábado, das 08:00h à 12:00h

Sei que consigo pegar o dia da semana com a função `DAYOFWEEK`.

Tenho a query que retorna a quantidade de registros agrupados pelo intervalo de horas:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN info = 1 THEN '0-4'
         WHEN info = 2 THEN '4-8'
         WHEN info = 3 THEN '8-16'
         WHEN info = 4 THEN '16-24'
         WHEN info = 5 THEN '24-32'
         WHEN info = 6 THEN '> 32'
       END as info, sum(value) as value
FROM (
   (SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, (  SELECT launch_date 
                                        FROM shipping 
                                        WHERE id = s.id AND DAYOFWEEK(launch_date) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
                                     ), 
                                      so.collection_expected_date) < 4 THEN 1
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.launch_date, so.collection_expected_date) BETWEEN 4 AND 8 THEN 2
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.launch_date, so.collection_expected_date) BETWEEN 8 AND 16 THEN 3
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.launch_date, so.collection_expected_date) BETWEEN 16 AND 24 THEN 4
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.launch_date, so.collection_expected_date) BETWEEN 24 AND 32 THEN 5
            WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s.launch_date, so.collection_expected_date) > 32 THEN 6
        END as info,
        count(*) as value 
    FROM shipping s
    INNER JOIN shipping_origin so ON (so.id = (SELECT id FROM shipping_origin WHERE shipping_id = s.id ORDER BY collection_expected_date LIMIT 1))
    WHERE s.shipper_id = :shipperId AND s.launch_date BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate 
        AND s.status not in ('CANCELED', 'EXPIRED', 'EXCLUDED') AND (:operationGroupId IS NULL OR s.shipper_operation_group_id = :operationGroupId) 
        AND s.freight_type = 'CIF'
    GROUP BY info
    ORDER BY info) UNION
    (SELECT 1 as info, 0 as value FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT 2 as info, 0 as value FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT 3 as info, 0 as value FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT 4 as info, 0 as value FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT 5 as info, 0 as value FROM dual) UNION
    (SELECT 6 as info, 0 as value FROM dual)
) a
GROUP BY info
```

Estou com dificuldades pra adequar essa query, considerando os dias úteis e os respectivos horários citados que citei na descrição.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Não seria preciso considerar os feriados também?

Comment: Para este cenário, não tem necessidade